# Force client to call specific method

Tags: java

In a library in `Java 7`, I have a class which services to other classes. It means, after creating an instance of service class, one method of that may be called several times (for example `doWork()` method). So I do not know when its task is completed. But service class uses heavy objects and it should release them. I set this part in a method, for example `release()` but it is not guaranteed that other developers use this method. Is there a way to force other developers to call this method after completing the task of service class? Of course I can document that, but I want to force them.

Note:

I can not call `release()` method in `doWork()` method, because `doWrok()`  needs to those objects when it is called in next.

Comment: Can you show code for this?

Comment: @johncena Sorry, the code is very long and complex. It consists of several classes.

Comment: Then your best approach is to implement finalize method and hope GC calls. And in finalize you can release these objects. But how that will work is not often predictable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same mechanism that many JDK classes use. Have a `close()` method that releases the resources, document it clearly that you must call `close()` after you're done with the object and have the class implement `AutoCloseable` (which also declares `close()`).

When a class implements `AutoCloseable`, you can use it in a `try-with-resources` clause, so you can write your code as

```
try(MyClass mc = new MyClass()) {
    mc.doWork();
    mc.doMoreWork();
    mc.someMoreWork();
} catch(SomeExceptionThatMayBeThrown e) {
    logger.log("Ooops", e);
}
```

It's a familiar idiom to anyone who's not totally new to Java, and some IDEs will also display a warning if an `AutoCloseable` isn't closed.

For additional points, you can implement the `finalize()` method that will clean up resources. However this is a safety mechanism, not something you should use as an alternative to explicit closing. This whole thing is pretty much how for example `FileInputStream` and similar JDK classes are implemented.

Answer (score 1):

There's no real way to force people if you don't know ahead of time how many calls there will be (how will you ever know if something is the last call?)

You can consider running some sort of static daemon thread that registers newly created objects and keeps an eye on how long they've been idle for, but you have to set a time limit.

Answer (score 1):

I think Kayaman's answer is generally the most correct one.

I am just trying to suggest an alternative, and it is not a solution applicable to every scenario

Instead of forcing the caller to call your release, you provide some facility for developer to put their work in.

For example:

```
FooService fooService = new FooService();
fooService.doWork();
System.out.println("hello");
fooService.doWork();
System.out.println("world");
fooService.release();   // oops, developer may forget to call this
```

You may provide something like a template method  which do something like:

```
class FooWorkTemplate {
    void doSafely(Consumer<FooService> work) {
        FooService fooService = new FooService();
        work.accept(fooService);
        fooService.release();
     }
}
```

so, caller can do something like

```
new FooWorkTemplate().doSafely( s -> {
        s.doWork();
        System.out.println("hello");
        s.doWork();
        System.out.println("world");
    });
```

Make it a convention for developer to follow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want release() to be called everytime your method is used, just call release() at the end of your method.

Comment: I suggest using a resource pool for the heavy objects. This way calling release() at the end of doWork() will only return the heavy object back to the pool and they can be used again.